# Debug WCF service in Console Application

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a service WCF with Visual Studio 2017 and a console application to test it.

[image]

ConsoleAppTestWCF has a service Reference to TestWCF. There is the main method in Programm.cs :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    Console.WriteLine("Give a value");

    String input = Console.ReadLine();
    int value;

    if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(client.GetData(value));
    }

    client.Close();
}
```

My question is : How can I do to debug (with breakpoints, etc) the web service (in this case `GetData` method) ?

Comment: Just right-click the solution and set both projects as startup. You will be able to put breakpoints on both sides

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried this, but I have no option to set both projects as startup. Only one by one.

Comment: Of course you can: https://i.stack.imgur.com/merTm.png

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto my bad, I was clicking on projects instead of solution. It works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CamiloTerevinto, there is the answer :

[image]

Right-click on solution. Select "Set StartUp Projects.."

[image]

Set both projects as startup.